# Binding to a nullable data type in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro, nullable

Well, this little quirk of `WPF` is really getting under my skin. So, I have a `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Rates" AlternatingRowBackground="#FCFCFC" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserSortColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding item}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Width ="*" Binding="{Binding rate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

It simply has a list of items in column A and we have to enter the rates in column B. Sounds simple enough.

Here is the property in the `ViewModel` to which it is bound.

```
private BindableCollection<Rate> _rates;

public BindableCollection<Rate> Rates
{
    get
    {
        return _rates;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value == _rates)
        {
            return;
        }

        _rates = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
    }
}
```

Here is the definition for `Rate`:

```
public partial class Rate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string client { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> rate { get; set; }
}
```

So, the second column of my `DataGrid` is getting bound to `Rate.rate` which is a `Nullable<decimal>`. Herein lies the problem. The `Nullable<decimal>` does accept `NULL` but the `TextBox` wouldn't let me enter a blank value. Moreover, if I type in some value like 5 and then delete it, the `ViewModel` retains the previous value.

I have seen solutions involving the `IValueConverter`, but I would prefer a XAML-based solution. Is there any? I have several modules where the `DataType` is `Nullable`, and it can quickly become very tedious if I have to use `IValueConverter` every time.

**EDIT**

I am using `Caliburn.Micro`, hence using `TargetNullValue=''` will not work everywhere, as the binding is automatic. It'll work in the above example, where the `binding` is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: One hack can be to replace Nullable decimal with string and then to validate user input or even to restrict user input to only allow decimal values by extending textbox class text changed event or previewKeydown event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Caliburn.Micro**, you can configure the way CM applies automatic bindings between your View and your ViewModel.

So in the `Configure` method of your `Bootstrapper` classe you can write something like:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    ConventionManager.SetBinding = delegate(Type viewModelType, string path, PropertyInfo property, FrameworkElement element, ElementConvention convention, DependencyProperty bindableProperty)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(path);
        ConventionManager.ApplyBindingMode(binding, property);
        ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter(binding, bindableProperty, property);
        ConventionManager.ApplyStringFormat(binding, convention, property);
        ConventionManager.ApplyValidation(binding, viewModelType, property);
        ConventionManager.ApplyUpdateSourceTrigger(bindableProperty, element, binding, property);

        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null)
        {
            binding.TargetNullValue = String.Empty;
        }

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, bindableProperty, binding);
    };

    // Your own configurations... 
}
```

As you can see this code sets the `TargetNullValue` property of the `Binding` if the source property is `Nullable`. It is applied to all automatic binding that CM creates for you in your application.

I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

About your last comment, consider that Caliburn Micro do not handle `FrameworkElement`s which are already binded (in the XAML) to a property when it applies the "automatic binding".

So if you want to automatically set the `TargetNullValue` of your "manual" bindings, well the simpliest idea is to create your own binding:

```
public class NullableBinding : Binding
{
    public NullableBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        TargetNullValue = String.Empty;
    }

    public NullableBinding()
        : base()
    {
        TargetNullValue = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

and then use it in your XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Width ="*" Binding="{local:NullableBinding rate}"/>
```

Comment: It did. The official answer from https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/448 didn't. Even when I changed `type` to `GetType()`.

Comment: Okay, tinkered with the code and finally this was working:
`var existingApplyValidation = ConventionManager.ApplyValidation;

            ConventionManager.ApplyValidation = (binding, viewModelType, property) => {
                existingApplyValidation(binding, viewModelType, property); // preserve existing behavior

                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) != null)
                    binding.TargetNullValue = String.Empty;
            };`

Your code helped. Copied the conditional statement from your code.

Comment: I was testing this solution, and it only works where Caliburn.Micro automatically binds the elements. For example it works here: `<TextBox x:Name="Age"/>`. But it does not work where binding is manually defined, like: `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Width ="*" Binding="{Binding rate}"/>`. Any way we can set the default TargetNullValue for application-wide bindings?

Comment: Thanks. That took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, customizing the binding in `ConventionManager`of `Caliburn` was the way to go.

Here is the solution:
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/448